# Cannot write to backup file

Tags: vim, macos-catalina, neovim

Since I have upgraded to Catalina, I cannot edit my dotfiles but get a message saying "Cannot write to backup file...".

I have checked the permissions on the file and my user account is the owner and has read and write permissions. If I edit the files with BBedit, I can save the files so the issue just seems to be editing within neovim.

I can also edit files using neovim in other directories but not within my dotfile directory.

**Additional information added:**

I have noticed that the files that I can't edit have the following permission structure:

```
.rwxrwxrwx@ 1.4k pdd 30 Aug  2017 plugin_manager.vim
```

I have now removed the @ attribute using `xattr` but that has not made any difference.

**Additional Information Update**
I have narrowed it down to something in my vimrc file. If I start neovim without my vimrc, I can save files in my vimrc directory.

I have the following code in my vimrc relating to backup files:

```
if exists('$SUDO_USER')
  set nobackup                        " don't create root-owned files
  set nowritebackup                   " don't create root-owned files
else
  set backupdir=~/local/.config/nvim/tmp/backup
  set backupdir+=~/.config/nvim/tmp/backup    " keep backup files out of the way
  set backupdir+=.
endif
```

If I comment these lines out, I can then save files in my vimrc directory. I am a little confused as I have had these in my vimrc for some time and have not had a problem.

I am probably missing something simple. Does anyone have any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

The original backup I used for vim was found here: https://vim.fandom.com/wiki/Incremental_backup_in_central_backup_directory created July 22, 2005 author Sylvain Lafleur

It doesn't work in neovim, but I was able to get it working:

I'm using KDE Neon. The original looks like it might work on windows, but I have not tested it.

A few things to note:

1. You will need to manually edit the **g:backupdir** and
   **g:this_root_backkup_dir** (This may be reduced, but I didn't mess with it.)
2. I was unable to make $HOME work, so use /home/username on linux.
3. This is not my actual directory structure, but should suffice as an
   example, in that /home/neon/vim existed before I used this code.
4. This is very redundant backup. Every time the file is saved it will
   create a backup of the filename with date/time stamp.
5. In the `.vimrc` put your vim specific code in `if !has('nvim')`
   and `endif` blocks. I put the following code in my `init.vim` file.

```
    set backup
    set backupcopy=yes
    
    function Write_backup()
      let g:backupdir='/home/neon/vim/vim_backups'
      let &backupdir=g:backupdir
      let g:backupext = strftime("_%Y-%m-%d_%H-%M-%S")
      let  &backupext=g:backupext
      let g:this_root_backup_dir = '/home/neon/vim/vim_backups'
      let g:this_dir = substitute(expand("%:p:h")," ","_","g")
      let g:this_filename = substitute(expand("%")," ","_","g")
      let g:this_drive = strpart(g:this_dir, 0, 1)
      let g:this_backup_dir_drive = g:this_root_backup_dir . g:this_drive
      let g:this_backup_dir = g:this_backup_dir_drive . strpart(g:this_dir, 1)
      
      "--make DRIVE directory if it doesn't exist
      if !filewritable(g:this_backup_dir_drive)
          silent! execute expand('!mkdir -p ' . g:this_backup_dir_drive)
      endif
      
      "--make directory under DRIVE if it doesn't exist
      if !filewritable(g:this_backup_dir)
          silent! execute expand('!mkdir -p ' . g:this_backup_dir)
      endif
      
      "--set new backup dir
      let g:backupdir = g:this_backup_dir
      let &backupdir=g:backupdir
    endfunction

    call Write_backup()
    inoremap <ESC> <ESC>:call Write_backup()<CR><C-l>
    " note the <C-l> clears the output so remove if testing with echo
```